# scale the fetching of data from database

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table containing email list and auto incremented ID on which indexing is done.

```
CREATE TABLE EMAIL_LIST
(
ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
email_ID varchar(255),
lastFetchedID int,
PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

CREATE INDEX PIndex ON EMAIL_LIST (ID);
```

Then i have multiple computers fetching email_ID uniquely, that is done to scale the process of fetching.
but the email_ID's to be fetched are described on condition.

```
SELECT lastFetchedID FROM EMAIL_LIST WHERE ID=1 FOR UPDATE;       // say this is x;       
UPDATE EMAIL_LIST SET lastFetchedID=lastFetchedID+100 WHERE ID=1;

SELECT email_ID FROM EMAIL_LIST WHERE ID>=x AND ID< x+100;
```

so that every computer has a distinct set of email_ID's

I just wanted to know if i use select for update, and in the same connection if i fetch 100 email_ID's will there be exclusive lock on the row where ID=1 for the entire transaction?

and what is the best way to achieve this, the number of computers can vary so i am doing this.

Comment: Personally I think you are approaching the problem from the wrong direction, instead of letting the workers split the job it would be more convenient to have a master process which splits the jobs for you.  If you know the amount of workers in advance this is fairly easy to do, you could even create a separate table with jobs where every worker gets a certain resultset from the database that way.

Comment: lastFetchedID is the ID till where the email_ID's has been fetched by any one of computer, any computer fetches 100 email_ID's at a time. so 1st any computer updates the lastFetchedID value and then fetches 100 email_ID's.

Comment: @Wolph the number of computers can vary and the table has millions of email_ID's. and if i knew the number of computers, i could have simply used modulus of ID

Comment: See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-transaction-model.html for information about how InnoDB locks during transactions.

Comment: @user2368055: in that case it could still be a good idea to just have a single computer create the "jobs". Just let it create batches with a given batchsize (any proper size should do) and add those to a job table with a `begin_id` and `end_id`. Every worker can simply loop and take 1 row at a time from the jobs table until it is empty.

Comment: `EMAIL_LIST` has millions of rows but there's only one common `lastFetchedID`?  So millions of repeats of the same value?  Why don't you just use a [separate sequence table](http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/172-how-to-use-sequence-generators-as-counters-in-mysql/)?

Answer (score 0):

From http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-locks-set.html:

> A locking read, an UPDATE, or a DELETE generally set record locks on every index record that is scanned in the processing of the SQL statement.

This means that a lock will be set on the row with `id = 1`.